# ASP.NET Core Authentication with NoSQL database

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework, asp.net-core, authentication

There have been so many changes with ASP.NET Core 3.0 that I am not sure where to start. My goal is to use MongoDB rather the SQL Server (EF) to store users and roles. I have read many answers but in particular I am looking at https://markjohnson.io/articles/asp-net-core-identity-without-entity-framework/. My web application is basically generated from ASP.NET Core web application with Angular. I now want to add Authorization to the web app. I have added the interceptors in Angular but when I start to debug this application I get 500 return with the stack:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IClientRequestParametersProvider' while attempting to activate 'BSoftSolutions.Controllers.OidcConfigurationController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: close
Host: localhost:44342
Referer: https://localhost:44342/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
```

I have an OidcConfigurationController that has a method

```
[HttpGet("_configuration/{clientId}")]
public IActionResult GetClientRequestParameters([FromRoute]string clientId)
{
    var parameters = ClientRequestParametersProvider.GetClientParameters(HttpContext, clientId);
    return Ok(parameters);
}
```

But that doesn't seem to be called. And this seems the source of the exception. I am not sure what GetClientParameters is suppose to return and how this figures into the whole authorization scheme. In the end is all I am after is to force the Authorization process use MongoDB rather than MS SQL.

I know this is a duplicate. But I am not able to tell what is applicable to Core 3.0 and Angular and what is not?

Comment: did you solve that?

Answer (score -2):

Latest 3.1 version just requires you to inject `IClientRequestParametersProvider (Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer)` in the `service/controller` layer

Comment: So simply add IClientRequestParametersProvider to the controller constructor parameters? This doesn't seem to cause the method to be called. Please more detail.

Comment: please, extend your answer. now it is just a comment